# Finding an integrating factor for a first-order ODE

Tags: differential-equations

First-order ODEs of the form $$P(x,y)dx+Q(x,y)dy=0$$ are said to be exact if $$\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}.$$ However, if the partial derivates are different, it can be found an integrating factor $\mu(x,y)$ such that, when multiplying the original ODE with it, it becomes exact: $$\frac{\partial (\mu P)}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial (\mu Q)}{\partial x}.$$

Is there any way to automatically finding an integrating factor for first-order ODEs with Mathematica?

Comment: Can you get one from the solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did not know there was a build-in function to find integrating factor, but here is a basic implementation from scratch.

In this, the form $m(x,y) dx + n(x,y) dy = 0$ is used, as I am more used to it. So in place of our $P$ it is now $m(x,y)$ and in place of your $Q$ it is now $n(x,y)$

You call it as

```
m = -2*Exp[2*x]*x^3 - 2*Exp[y];
n = Exp[y] x;
getIntegratingFactor[m, n, x, y]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
m = Exp[y] - x; n = Exp[y]*(Exp[y] + x);
getIntegratingFactor[m, n , x, y]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
m = 2*x*y; n = -2*x^2 + y^2;
getIntegratingFactor[m, n , x, y]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
m = -(-x y - 1);
n = (4 x^3 y - 2 x^2);
getIntegratingFactor[m, n , x, y]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
m = x^2 + y^2 + 2 x; n = 2 y;
getIntegratingFactor[m, n , x, y]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### code

```
getPatterns[expr_, pat_] := 
  Last@Reap[expr /. a : pat :> Sow[a], _, Sequence @@ #2 &];

getIntegratingFactor[m_, n_, x_, y_] := Module[{a, b, r, s, mu, t},
   (*find integrating factor for m*dx+n*dy=0*)
   (*version 1.0 alpha, July 9, 2020 10 AM*)
   
   If[Simplify[D[m, y] - D[n, x] == 0],
    Return["It is allready exact, no integrating factor needed",Module]];
   
   a = Simplify[(D[m, y] - D[n, x])/n];
   If[Length[getPatterns[a, y]] == 0,
    Return[Row[{"Integrating factor is mu=",Exp[Integrate[a, x]]}], Module]];
   
   b = Simplify[(D[n, x] - D[m, y])/m];
   If[Length[getPatterns[b, x]] == 0,
    Return[Row[{"Integrating factor is mu=", Exp[Integrate[b, y]]}],Module]];

   r = (D[n, x] - D[m, y])/(x*m - y*n);
   r = Simplify[r];
   r = r /. (x^s_.*y^s_.) -> t^s;
   If[Length[getPatterns[r, x]] == 0 && Length[getPatterns[r, y]] == 0,
     mu = Simplify[Exp[Integrate[r, t]]];
     mu = mu /. t -> (x*y);
     Return[Row[{"Integrating factor is mu=", mu}], Module]
    ,
     Print["Unable to find integrating factor"];
   ]
   ];
```

The helper function `getPatterns` used above is thanks to Carl Woll.

To help clarify the code above, here is Fortran-like flow chart of the algorithm. Drawing done using ipe Latex drawing diagram.

[image]

Bug reports are always welcome.

Comment: It is a good code.  Its very compact but difficult to read for novice.   For example, I could  not see step where t=xy is defined and then testing A and B for t.  I got it later.  I think it can be expanded for other values of t.  Good work.

Comment: @Aschoolar **I could not see step where t=xy is defined and then testing A and B for t** it is done in this code `r = r /. (x^s_.*y^s_.) -> t^s;` near 70% down the code with the code that follows that. That handle the last case in the chart (the R case)

Answer (score 5):

There's an internal function used to construct the solution.  If you don't want to reverse-engineer an integrating factor from the solution, you can use `` DSolve`DSolveFirstOrderODEDump`IntegratingFactor ``:

```
Block[{P, Q},
 P = (Cos[x] - Sin[x]) Sin[y];
 Q = Cos[x] Cos[y];
 mu = DSolve`DSolveFirstOrderODEDump`IntegratingFactor[
   Q, P, -D[P, y] + D[Q, x], x, y];
 mu -> D[mu*P, y] - D[mu*Q, x] // Simplify
 ]
```

> ```
> (*  E^x -> 0  *)
> ```

Returns `$Failed` when it fails:

```
Block[{P, Q},
 P = E^(x y);
 Q = Cos[x] Cos[y];
 mu = DSolve`DSolveFirstOrderODEDump`IntegratingFactor[
   Q, P, -D[P, y] + D[Q, x], x, y];
 mu -> D[mu*P, y] - D[mu*Q, x] // Simplify
 ]
```

> ```
> (*  $Failed -> $Failed (E^(x y) x + Cos[y] Sin[x])  *)
> ```

Comment: thanks for pointing out this function. I am still trying to figure how to use it to reproduce the results I have. But will try to figure it out.

Comment: @Nasser If I substitute `P=m`, `Q=n`, I get all your results.